# Animate a <div> with jQuery

Tags: jquery

I am looking for an option to move a `<div>` on the page when the page is loaded.
The `<div>` contains a chat window.

The box must fall down slowly to the bottom of the page and land on the footer.
How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check out the .animate() function, which can be used to smoothly move div's and other elements over the page: [Animate](http://api.jquery.com/animate/).

Additionally, the div can be added at page load as such:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('body').append('<div id="chatwindow">Hello World!</div>');
});
```

Comment: Thanks Cpt, it looks great... but how can i move the div to a particular position on the footer... so when the page loads, the div can be dropped from top of the page to the bottom footer.

Comment: you want to set the div's css to `position: absolute;` and animate it from `bottom: 0;` to the bottom of the screen, or the bottom of the document, wherever you want it to go.

Comment: I used animate function like: $(".block").animate({"bottom": "0", "left": "+=0px"}, "slow"); It is sliding slow... but can i still reduce the speed of sliding, as iam not able to realize the sliding effect due to my fast internet connection..

Comment: Instead of using the term 'fast' or 'slow', you can also specify a number, which represents the speed in milliseconds. Try 2000 or 4000 to get a slower animation.

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to use jquery .animate():

http://api.jquery.com/animate/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('body').append('<div id="chatwindow">Hello World!</div>');

  $('#chatwindow').animate({
    bottom: '0', //you'll want to set this to whatever it needs to be to be at the bottom
  }, 5000, function() {
    //completion code?
  });
});
```

Comment: Hi, but the animations are not working well in IE and Chrome, as i could not see the animation. I tried to decrease the speed, but no use. What i can do...

Comment: Still having a problem with this? Sorry. I was away.

Comment: Excellent. Glad we could help you :)

Comment: @JamesThompson, This is something I'd like to do too. But for me, your code makes my div just appear suddenly without sliding... Any idea what the issue might be?